# Template instantiation Issues

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, instantiation

I am using library file Slist.h which has template declaration and definition.The library file is instantiated in the construtor 
of mypgm.c(cpp file).The compiler throws an error which is mentioned at the bottom.

**Slist.h**

```
template <class Object>
class SList;     // fwd declaration.
template <class Object>
class SListItr;  // fwd declaration.
template <class Object>
class SListNode
{
    SListNode( const Object &theElement = Object( ),
               SListNode *n = NULL )
      : element( theElement ), next( n ) { }

    Object     element;
    SListNode *next;
    friend class SList<Object>;
    friend class SListItr<Object>;
};

template <class Object>
class SList
{
  public:
    SList( );
    SList( const SList &rhs );
    ~SList( );
    int isEmpty( ) const;
    void makeEmpty( );
    SListItr<Object> zeroth( ) const;
    SListItr<Object> first( ) const;
    const SList & operator=(  SList &rhs );
    int  IsType() {return LinkedListType;};
  private:
    SListNode<Object> *header;
    Object *ptr_Object;
};

//SList definition
template <class Object>
SList<Object>::SList( )
{
     ptr_Object = new Object();
     header = new  SListNode<Object>; 
}

// Copy constructor.
template <class Object>
SList<Object>::SList( const SList<Object> &rhs )
{
    header = new SListNode<Object>; 
    *this = rhs;
}

// Destructor.
template <class Object>
SList<Object>::~SList( )
{
    makeEmpty( );
    delete ptr_Object;
    delete header;
}
```

**mypgm.c**

```
class mypgm
{
public:
    mypgm::mypgm()
    {
    ptr_dead_acc_list= new SList<String>; // ptr_dead_acc_list is of type SList<String>
    }
 };
```

**String class details for your reference**

```
class String
{
        private:
                char *_text;
                friend class String_Iterator;
        public:
                // ctors and dtor
                explicit String ();                     
                explicit String (char *);
                explicit String (int );
                String (String& );              
                ~String();

                /////////////////
                // conversions:
                /////////////////
                //  to C-like type char *
                operator char *() {return _text;}

                /////////////////
                // overloads:
                /////////////////
                // assignment String = String
                String &operator=(String &);
}
```

**Compilation Error:**

```
SList.h: In constructor 'SList<Object>::SList() [with Object = String]':
mypgm.c:131:   instantiated from here
SList.h:85: error: no matching function for call to 'String::String(String)'
String.h:27: note: candidates are: String::String(String&)
SList.h:41: error: in passing argument 1 of 'SListNode<Object>::SListNode(const Object&, SListNode<Object>*) [with Object = String]'
SList.h: In constructor 'SListNode<Object>::SListNode(const Object&, SListNode<Object>*) [with Object = String]':
SList.h:85:   instantiated from 'SList<Object>::SList() [with Object = String]'
mypgm.c:131:   instantiated from here
SList.h:42: error: passing 'const String' as 'this' argument of 'String::operator char*()' discards qualifiers
make: *** [all]
```

I feel that the arguments are not passed correctly during instant ion,i have tried to resolve this ,but my steps are in vain.
i am new to template concept.could you please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks for looking into this

Answer (score 4):

Your problem has nothing doThe copy constructor of `String` should accept a reference to constant. Instead of this:

```
String (String& );
```

The signature should look like this:

```
String(String const&);
```

`SListNode` is invoking the constructor of `String` on a constant object, and the compiler complains because your copy-constructor accepts a non-constant reference:

```
SListNode( const Object &theElement = Object( ),
           SListNode *n = NULL )
  : element( theElement ), // ERROR: theElement is a reference to const!
    next( n ) { }
```

Also notice, that although your problem stems from the instantiation of a template, it is not specifically related to templates. Doing the same thing in non-template code would result in the same error.

Comment: Indeed, I would further clarify that this issue has nothing to do with templates.

Comment: @RyanWitmer: True, I made that explicit

Comment: @Andy Prowl: Thanks a lot Andy for the quick response.I will try and let you know.I have one more question,I am calling the below parametrised constructor (header = new  SListNode<Object>; ) 

SListNode( const Object &theElement = Object( ),
               SListNode *n = NULL )
      : element( theElement ), next( n ) { }

Please refer SList definition code in my question

Comment: @user2040497: What is the question?

Comment: In the above code, I am calling the below parametrised constructor(header = new SListNode<Object>; ) 
consutructor:-
SListNode( const Object &theElement = Object( ), SListNode *n = NULL ) : element( theElement ), next( n ) { } Please refer SList definition code in my question. 
1.Is it the correct way to invoke the parameterized constructor of a template?
2.Do i need to pass any parameter during instantiation?

Comment: @user2040497: 1. Yes; 2. Not necessarily.

Comment: @ANdy Prowl:Thank You very much

Comment: I have modified the copy constructor as constant,the compiler throws an error because calling a non-const method from a const method.Definition of copy cons `String::String(String const& string) { _text = new char[string.length() + 1]; strcpy(_text,string); }` **Error:** String.c: In copy constructor 'String::String(const String&)':
String.c:error: passing 'const String' as 'this' argument of 'int String::length()' discards qualifiers
String.c:error:passing 'const String'as 'this' argument f 'String::operator char*()'discards qualifiers
String.c:51:valid conversion fromchar*to'const char*'

Answer (score 0):

That error has nothing to do with the templates, it just happened to pop up while instantiating a template.  Your class `String` is unusual because it is not "CopyConstructible", which prevents using it in many of the normal ways.

It should probably have a constructor

```
String(const String&);
```

instead of

```
String(String&);
```